# Data definition has no type or storage class with float array definition

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'll probably find the answer soon enough by blind experimentation or a better Google search, but..  This might benefit others.

This is NOT inside a class definition, but is in a .m objective-c file.  I've got a declaration of a float array that is giving me the following two warnings in Xcode.  The errors show up on the DECLARATION line, not the assignment line.

Data declaration has no type or storage class.
Type defaults to 'int' in declaration

Then an assignment fails - but if the variable is defaulting to int, that would happen.

Here's the code.  The first declaration (static const float array with initializer) doesn't give an error, nor does the second (simple float).  The third and forth (float arrays) do.

```
static const float offset3d[4] = {
    0.0, 0.0, -2.0, 0.0
};
float boxv;
float boxv0[3];
float boxv1[3];

boxv0[0] = -0.5;
// this gives the error of trying to assign float to (default) int
```

Comment: Are you doing the assignment outside a function block?

Comment: Yeah - I changed the declaration to the form of the first one (offset3d) without any assignment statement other than the initializer.  My question now is how the writer of the code got it to compile.  Earlier version of GCC that was more forgiving of "non initializer initializers"?

Comment: Ha, you’ve posted your comment whilst I was typing my answer. I have no idea if previous GCC versions (or other compilers) allow this kind of initialisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put `boxv0[0] = -05.;` inside a method somewhere. Each of your declarations should work, and the assignment should fail. Your first assignment works because you completely assign the declared array- this is acceptable because the compiler can create the memory location and fill it. The last one fails because you attempt to modify it dynamically outside a class method, which the compiler does not allow. Finally, if you are getting warnings on the declarations, you might have something else going on.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are trying to do the assignment

```
boxv0[0] = -0.5;
```

outside of a function block, which is not allowed. Outside of function blocks, only declarations (with or without initialisers) are allowed. The warning messages you are getting are due to the fact that C traditionally implies `int` when no type has been specified so, outside of a function block,

```
someVariable = 5;
```

is implicitly typed as `int`, i.e., the above definition is equivalent to

```
int someVariable = 5;
```

When the compiler sees

```
boxv0[0] = -0.5;
```

outside of a function block, it notices there is no type specification, so it assumes `int` (which gives a warning). Then it realises that `boxv0` was previously declared as `float`, so it gives a conflicting types error.

If you need to initialise `boxv0` outside of a function block, do it like you did for `offset3d`, e.g.

```
float boxv0[3] = {
    -0.5f, -1.0f, -1.5f
};
```